# Why was my recent comment deleted?

Tags: support, comments

On my recent post:
[What is the order of mitzvot importance?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/131313/what-is-the-order-of-mitzvot-importance)
I responded to a comment with a meaningful and helpful response. Why was my comment removed?

Answer (score 2):

It responded to a comment containing an inquiry that is no longer there. Comments may be deleted when they are no longer serving their purpose; that's not a punishment as much as site hygiene.

Comment: No, it was responding to the comment that you posted, which is still present on the post

Comment: I commented "Why assume there is only one way of ordering?" You wrote "There are many ways of ordering. I am referring to order of importance". I question strongly to what extent that was a "meaningful and helpful response" since the question was clearly already about orders of importance. But anyway now there is a comment "Why assume there is only one way of ordering importance?" which is more precise and which your comment wouldn't even make sense as a response to.